# Save and load Resource failing with "Error constructing a GDScriptInstance"

Tags: gdscript, godot-4

I have this specific `Resource` script:

```python
class_name MyDataStructure
extends Resource

@export var title: String = "Default Title"
@export var medals_per_world = {
    "world1": {
        "bronze": 0,
        "silver": 0,
        "gold": 0,
    },
    # Etc.
}

func _init(_some_title: String):
    title = _some_title
```

And I'm trying to save/load it with these methods:

```python
const SAVE_DATA_PATH := "user://save_game.tres"
var _data: MyDataStructure

func _on_button_save_pressed():
    ResourceSaver.save(_data, SAVE_DATA_PATH)

func _on_button_load_pressed():
    if not ResourceLoader.exists(SAVE_DATA_PATH):
        return
    _data = load(SAVE_DATA_PATH)
```

**Saving works fine** and gives me this type of file:

```python
[gd_resource type="Resource" script_class="MyDataStructure" load_steps=2 format=3]

[ext_resource type="Script" path="res://my_data_structure.gd" id="1_e2e3s"]

[resource]
script = ExtResource("1_e2e3s")
title = "Foo title"
medals_per_world = {
"world1": {
"bronze": 3,
"gold": 2,
"silver": 4
}
}
```

**Loading it fails** with this error:

> ```
> E 0:00:07:0699   root.gd:31 @ _on_button_load_pressed(): Error constructing a GDScriptInstance.
>   <C++ Error>    Method/function failed. Returning: nullptr
>   <C++ Source>   modules/gdscript/gdscript.cpp:183 @ _create_instance()
>   <Stack Trace>  root.gd:31 @ _on_button_load_pressed()
> ```

I recently introduced the nested dictionary `medals_per_world` so perhaps that's causing me issues?

Either way, how can I properly load such a file with the `ResourceLoader`? The fact that it saves properly suggests that loading it should also be possible? Or is my only workaround/solution to define the entire data structure with dto `Resource` scripts for each nested level if the dictionary is the cause?

I'm working with Godot 4 so can use any recently released GDScript feature if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Godot will try to call your `_init` method while loading the `Resource`. But it can't because it has a non-optional parameter (Godot has no means to figure out what to pass).

Thus, a possible solution is to make it optional:

```
func _init(_some_title: String = ""):
    title = _some_title
```

Alternatively, you could remove it entirely.

---

You could also take control of how the `Resource` is loaded by implementing a `ResourceFormatLoader` which you register with `ResourceLoader.add_resource_format_loader`.

*Alternatively - in particular if you need to be able to load the `Resource` from the editor - you could be interested in implementing `EditorImportPlugin` which you register from an `EditorPlugin` using `EditorPlugin.add_import_plugin`.*

Then your implementation can use your `_init` correctly.

---

As an alternative to adding parameters to `_init` you can add static methods to build your type※:

```
static func with_title(_some_title:String) -> MyDataStructure:
    var result = MyDataStructure.new()
    result.title = _some_title
    return result
```

※: *Doing this in Godot 3.x would have required a helper class, because Godot would not resolve the name of the class while parsing the class.*

That might also improve readability of your code. For example, anybody unfamiliar with your code, and without looking up the definition, could guess that argument is a title:

```
var instance := MyDataStructure.with_title("BLAH")
```

*By the way: Godot does not support named arguments.*

Comment: Cheers! Classic mistake by me, I changed _two_ things at once (nested dictionary _and_ another `_init` parameter) and blamed one of them for the error. Incorrectly, it seems. Heck, even in my repro I neatly repeated the double mistake.  The constructor argument lacking a default was indeed the issue!